# WPF - How does Parent know of on "Checked" event for child control checkbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, user-controls, wpf-controls

I have a child control that has a checkbox and webbrowser:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Some.MyUserControl" etc.>
  <Grid>
    <CheckBox x:Name="chkA" Content="Analysis" Checked="chkA_Checked"></CheckBox>
    <WebBrowser Margin="0,30,0,0" Name="wbA"></WebBrowser>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I am putting this control in my MainWindow.xaml/.cs:

```
<Window x:Class Some.MainWindow xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Some" etc.>
  <Grid>
    <local:MyUserControl x:Name="MyUserControl_Main"></local:MyUserControl>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

My question is how can my MainWindow know that the CheckBox (chkA) has been checked?  So far only the actual user control knows it has been clicked?  How can I expose the "Checked" event for my MainWindow to see?  Or is there a better way?

I've searched the web, but can't seem to wrap my head around what I'm seeing.

Thank you in advance,

-newb

**EDIT 1:**

I am trying the following with no luck, but may be on the right track.

Within my MainWindow.xaml.cs I have added:

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent CheckedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("Checked", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(MyUserControl));

public event RoutedEventHandler Checked
{
    add { AddHandler(CheckedEvent, value); }
    remove { RemoveHandler(CheckedEvent, value); }
}
```

And within MyUserControl.xaml.cs I have added:

```
private void chkA_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RoutedEventArgs args = new RoutedEventArgs(MainWindow.CheckedEvent);
    RaiseEvent(args);
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

Moved previously mentioned code into MyUserControl.xaml.cs:

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent CheckedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("Checked", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(MyUserControl));

public event RoutedEventHandler Checked
{
    add { AddHandler(CheckedEvent, value); }
    remove { RemoveHandler(CheckedEvent, value); }
}

private void chkA_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RoutedEventArgs args = new RoutedEventArgs(MainWindow.CheckedEvent);
    RaiseEvent(args);
}
```

And now I am able to see the "Checked" event "Bubble" up as so:

```
<Window x:Class Some.MainWindow xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Some" etc.>   
  <Grid>     
    <local:MyUserControl x:Name="MyUserControl_Main" **Checked="MyUserControl_Main_Checked"**></local:MyUserControl>   
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Thanks @Matt for the tip!

**EDIT 3:**

Matt's first answer is the best way to go, I had it "Checkbox" vs "CheckBox"... Adding CheckBox.Checked to the grid catches the event:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the `Checked` event bubble up to the parent and catch it there. It's the beauty of routed events!

```
<Grid CheckBox.Checked="CheckBox_Checked">
    <local:MyUserControl x:Name="MyUserControl_Main" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test this, but I'm 99% certain it'll work even if the CheckBoxes are inside a UserControl. Certainly it works if they're in a DataTemplate.

Comment: @Matt-Hamilton
Thanks for the response, I've editted my questions with additional info as I look more into routed events.

Comment: @Mike - you don't need any extra code. All you need, as per my answer, is to handle CheckBox.Checked in the "host" Window somewhere and any Checked event in your UserControl will bubble up to there.

Comment: @Matt-Hamilton 
You were totally right the first time, my typo caused my a "The attached property 'Checked' was not found in type 'Checkbox'."  So I went looking up routed events.

At least now I know more about routed events.  Thanks for the help, it is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but you should declare the routed event in `MyUserControl`, not in `MainWindow`... it's the user control that is raising the event, not the window. The way you're doing it, your control is explicitly depending on `MainWindow`, which is bad practice and not necessary.